# How to avoid "exit" in user defined library programs for my container server in C?

Tags: c, linux, unix, overriding, exit

I'm writing a container server for library in C.

The system library dl, as dynamic linking loader, is used to implement the programming interface. That is `dlopen`/`dlsym` function.

To return control to the container server, both `return` and `exit` could be used. The `return` is ok.

But the `exit()` in users' program will lead the container server to exit too.

How can I support exit in users' programs?

I'm thinking to override the `exit` function while invoking dynamic linking loader.

Comment: The child process module was denied in the original design. Because the applications user defined were strongly depending on the container server's context.

Comment: Function setjmp and longjmp will be used to replace exit in user's program. Thanks for Danny Beckett, User1 and Tuxdude.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're writing just a library, it cannot run on its own without a process invoking it.

As soon as the application exits, the state of your library would also be lost unfortunately.

In other words, if you want to maintain the state even after the application exits, you would probably need to write an Initialization Daemon which is always the first process to initialize this library and keeps running in the background as a means to maintain the state of your container.

You would also need to use semaphores or some form of IPC to ensure the state is propagated between the daemon and other client processes using this library.

Comment: Sorry, I'm writing a container server, that's a standard linux process. The application programs are from users.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should create a new child process for running the library function which may call `exit()`.
When the library function calls `exit()` or returns, then the child process will exit, and the parent process (the container server) will get information about the termination of child.

In this case easiest way to start new a child process, is to call `fork()`. Using of `system()` call is not needed in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The child process module was denied in the original design. Because the applications user defined were strongly depending on the container server's context. I'll add the limitation in main topic. 
C